# TVOS: UIButton action not working in subview

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton, tvos

in the TVOS Application storyboard mainview I added a subview.
Within the subview there are 3 button created in the very same way (the code here belongs to the subview)

```
UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem]; 
b.frame = CGRectMake(left, top,     400, size);
[b setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[b addTarget:self action:@selector(Action_Up) forControlEvents:UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered];  
[self.view addSubview:b];  
...
-(void)Action_Up {  
    [self ShowData];  
}
```

in the simulator and on the real device I can select the button and press it, but the action is never fired.

Could you help ?

Comment: Pretty much the same problem here, can't even solve it using pressesBegan:WithEvent:

Comment: Who has the focus? the button or the view ?

Comment: I guess the button, because it can be selected by the remote.

Comment: Check whether the button frame is inside the view's frame. In some case, if the view's frame is smaller than the button's position, then everything works fine except the user interaction. You can easily find this easily by adding bg color to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. it worked for me

```
        button.addTarget(self, action: "someMethodName:", forControlEvents: .PrimaryActionTriggered)
```