# Programmatically addTarget action to UIButton

Tags: uibutton, tvos, swift3

I tested a ton of samples but none of them works for me. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.sizeToFit()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button tapped.")
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

Well, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936825/tvos-uibutton-action-not-working-in-subview?rq=1) the issue is with `.touchUpInside`. In tvOS it should be `.primaryActionTriggered`.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonTapped(_:)), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
```